# Mongodb First insert slower than rest

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a Java web app that creates sets of mongodb documents in a loop and bulk inserts them using Spring's MongoTemplate.

Strangely the performance on the first insert is far worse than subsequent inserts. 
Here's an example of the performance with 3 sets of documents:

- insert 15 documents 3.1 seconds
- insert 10 documents 16 ms
- insert 20 documents 19 ms

This is very consistent.  Re-running the same junit over and over results in the same performance characteristics.

Any ideas of how to eliminate that first insert slowness or what might be causing it?

Thanks

Comment: Pre-insert a document "before the first" document then delete it so that the *real* first document will be fast ;-)

Comment: Seriously though, does it really matter?  Inserting the first document in a collection is a one-time thing so if you plan to add lots of documents into the same collection that initial cost will amortize out to practically nothing.

Comment: Well if its junit it's probably still do class loading and various other reflection that will be cached subsequent calls. The first of anything is slow in Java.

Comment: It matters in that it pisses me off and makes my app look slow when it should be faster. The requests coming in should be responded to quickly and this is causing 4 second responses instead of 1 second responses.

Comment: @AdamGent I'm only timing what is happening within the server code. Yes, the junit start up stuff is slow but I'm not measuring that. Just the time before and after the inserts.

Comment: So it does happen multiply times during run time?

Comment: My guess is that is some reflection cache that is expiring to quickly or connection pooling is not in place or misconfigured.

Comment: It's consistent that each request that I send containing multiple sets will always be slow with the first one. My testing is to continue to re-run the junit that makes this request over and over and I see the same thing every time.

Comment: @AdamGent I'm using jndi to create a MongoTemplate (spring data) and autowiring that bean into my service.

Comment: Could it be related to the way that mongo connections are opened and closed?  Seems to me like it's opening a new connection for the first insert and re-using it for the next 2.  Hard to tell from the mongo log though.  I don't know how long they stay alive for.

Comment: Looking at the mongo log, every time I send the request it opens a new connection to mongo even though the log shows that there are other connections still open.

Comment: From the mongo log file, each connection open correlates to a call from my request:
[initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49986 #5 (1 connection now open)
[conn5]  authenticate db: 
[initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50113 #6 (2 connections now open)
[conn6]  authenticate db: 
[initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56270 #7 (3 connections now open)
[conn7]  authenticate db: 
[initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:59169 #8 (4 connections now open)
[conn8]  authenticate db: 
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most MongoDB drivers do not infinitely keep the socket connection to the sever open by default. Look into connection pooling setup and specifically as documented for the base driver http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/MongoOptions.html#socketKeepAlive

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. Any idea how I apply the MongoOptions to the Spring MongoTemplate?

Comment: This worked, thank you Neil Lunn!:

`Mongo mongo = new MongoClient(host, port);
MongoOptions options = mongo.getMongoOptions();
options.setSocketKeepAlive(true);
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongo, db,
     new UserCredentials(username, password));`

I'm now processing the entire thing (generating 3 sets of documents and bulk inserting them) in 60 ms!